# error C2065: 'CR_HASTE_MELEE' : undeclared identifier

Tags: c++

I am having problems referencing an Enumeration from one header file to another.

I have "**Unit.h**" which contains:

```
enum CombatRating
{
    CR_HASTE_MELEE              = 17,
    CR_HASTE_RANGED             = 18,
    CR_HASTE_SPELL              = 19,
};
```

Then "**Object.h**" which contains:

```
    void ApplyPercentModFloatValue(uint16 index, float val, bool apply)
    {
        float value = GetFloatValue(index);
        ApplyPercentModFloatVar(value, val, apply);
            if (apply && index == CR_HASTE_MELEE && value > 130.86f)
                value = 130.86f;
        SetFloatValue(index, value);
    }
```

When I build my project, I receive "error C2065: 'CR_HASTE_MELEE' : undeclared identifier". I tried an include for "Unit.h" within "Object.h" but that gives me loads of errors too.

Is there any way to reference the Enum across header files so that a percentage can be applied to "CR_HASTE_MELEE"?

Thanks

Comment: Did you include the header?

Comment: When I include the header I get loads of errors.

Comment: That's not very descriptive. You need to include the header with the enum to use the enum, though.

Comment: Sorry, here are my errors http://pastebin.com/0bqKMLW3

Comment: I don't suppose unit.h includes object.h. You'll need to move the enum to a new header if you want to use it in both if that's the case.

Comment: Correct, Unit.h doesn't include Object.h. Is that my problem?

Comment: That will just most likely bring up circular dependencies. Without more code and without unit.h including object.h (even indirectly), I don't know.

Comment: Actually, sorry Object.h IS included in Unit.h, they both have the include but I still receive errors. Thanks

Comment: Well, generally two headers including each other will not work. You'll have to rethink that design.

Comment: Ok thanks Chris. Appreciate your support.